# How to secure PHP form that retains values on form error?

Tags: php, html, forms

I need a form that retains it's values on error, but makes sure the input data is clean security wise.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div>
         <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="first_name" value="$_POST['first_name']"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

What should I do to the $_POST['first_name'] to make it safe and not vulnerable?

Comment: escape the variable so it renders on page properly and doesn't break the HTML, that's about all you should be doing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to remove any possiblity of harmful XSS attacks:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="first_name" value="'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name']).'"/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Not vulnerable to what? SQL injection?

You want to make a variable that will clean the data if there's any there, but won't throw an error when you first load the page (And ther'es no post data)

so:

```
$fname = !empty($_POST['first_name']) ? cleanstuff($_POST['first_name']) : ''

<form>
...
<input...value="<?php echo $fname; ?>"/>
</form>
```

Where "cleanstuff" is whatever function you need to clean your data, mysql_real_escape_string() if cleaning for mysql database or htmlentities() or whatever.  Preferably, a user-defined function that does all the cleaning you need for your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Data is vulnerable in context. For example, user-submitted HTML tags are fine to store in a database. If you echo them to the browser, then you've got a problem. For this reason, making something "not vulnerable" is a bit broad.

To make the user data safe to echo back into the form input, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div>
         <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo htmlentities $_POST['first_name']);"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

use htmlentities on webform and do the use *_real_escape_srting to deal with sql injection on your server php code

Answer (score -1):

htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name'])

This will escape any HTML in the string.

Comment: You're assuming he's putting it in a MySQL DB and using an old/non-maintained function! What about XSS!?

Comment: -1 `mysql_real_escape_string()` is for escaping input strings when injecting them in SQL queries when using the `mysql_*` library to connect to your MySQL database. This is not useful for escaping HTML output to counter [cross site scripting (XSS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) and similar attacks.

Answer (score -1):

Sanitizing data is not a one stop shop, it is important to properly validate all inputs, here are the steps required:

```
$first_name = trim($_POST['first_name']); //remove spaces
$first_name = htmlspecialchars($first_name); //convert special chars to html entities (for XSS)
$first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($first_name); //escape quotes for MySQL

//Now it is important to validate the data (confirm that the name is a name, only contains characters which can be in a name
```

Comment: It's important to only do what is required for what you are using the data for. For this question, that means making sure it's HTML safe, not safe for a database, and not trimmed.

Comment: I will assume, and hope, that the purpose of the form is not to display the First Name of the user back to the user who inputted the text. Hence the comments for each line that can be removed or added depending on what's being done with the data. I will also assume someone who does not know how to make input "HTML safe" does not know the next steps in securing his web application.

Comment: I'm assuming that the same people down-voting are the people who are up-voting the htmlspecialchars solution which is not context-aware and mentions no validation of the data.

Answer (score -4):

You can use many different functions to sanitize an inputted value. I recommend

```
<?php
//You have many options. You can use htmlspecialchars() to sanitize for XSS (Cross Site Scripting) and mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent SQL Injection. If you are using a MySQL database, I'd recommend both.
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name']));
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<div>
     <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<? echo $name; ?>"/>
</div>
```